# Convert Mouse pos into direction and back

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to ask what would be the best formula to convert mouse X,Y position into one of 16 directiones from player position.

I work in c++ ,sfml 1.6 so I get every position easily, but I dont know how to convert them based on angle from player position or something. (I was never good on math and for more than 4 directions `if` statements looks too complex).

Also I want to send it to server which converts direction back into delta X,Y so he can do something like:

```
player.Move(deltaX * speed * GetElapsedTime(), ...Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way would be to convert your two sets of co-ordinates (one for current player position, one for current mouse position) into an angle relative to the player's position, where an angle of 0 is the line straight ahead of the player (or north, depending on how your game works). Then each of your sixteen directions would translate to a given 22.5 degree interval.

However, since you said you're bad at math, I imagine you're looking for something more concrete than that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) to get the angle between the mouse position and the positive X axis:

```
#include <cmath>

float player_x = ...;
float player_y = ...;
float mouse_x = ...;
float mouse_y = ...;

float angle = std::atan2(mouse_y - player_y, mouse_x - player_x);
```

The `angle` returned by [`std::atan2()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) is a value between `-M_PI` (exclusive) and `M_PI` (inclusive):

```
-M_PI           Left (-180°)
-0.5 * M_PI     Down (-90°)
 0              Right (0°)
 0.5 * M_PI     Up (90°)
 M_PI           Left (180°)
```

You can transform this value depending on how you want your mapping to "one of 16 directions", i.e., depending on what value you want to assign to which discrete direction.

Given the angle, getting a unit vector to represent the X/Y delta is quite easy, too:

```
float dx = std::cos(angle);
float dy = std::sin(angle);
```